# Deployed Contract Doesn't Show up

Tags: ganache, brownie

I deploy a smart contract using Brownie to local Ganache blockchain (GUI, not CLI). I can see every transaction that I do and accounts (tx-count). However, the contract tab is always empty and asks me to connect to the Truffle project.

Is Ganache GUI not working with Brownie or something? Here is the code.

```
from brownie import accounts, SimpleStorage

def main():
    # accounts[0] refers to the first account in the Ganache.
    deploy_contract()


def deploy_contract():
    account = accounts.load("ganache-gui")
    SimpleStorage.deploy({"from": account})
    print(account)
```